# Stick inline-block divs to the bottom of another inline-block div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is situation I need to fix. And I really don't know what to use. Is it possible with CSS or we need to use jQuery?

```
<div class="parrent_wrap">
   <h1></h1>
   <div></div>
</div>

.parrent_wrap
{
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 265px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you post a more complete code example? it only has one div, so there is nothing to align. each box in the image is a .parrent_wrap?

Comment: It also has wrapper div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you're looking for is called Masonry. Check out http://masonry.desandro.com/

You will need to modify your code a bit and float the elements left but it should solve the problem.

Comment: note that if you have irregularly sized blocks you might want to look at some of masonry's "descendants" to achieve a grid without 'holes' - personally i like [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) with the [perfectmasonry](https://github.com/zonear/isotope-perfectmasonry) layout plugin.  he also made something called [packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) which is even more advanced in many ways but not necessarily as broadly useful

Comment: In this case because the columns are fixed you will wind up with the desired results. That said there are a number of good plugins available for perfect masonry. I wrote one of them ;)